# How to eliminate repited values from result of Oracle LISTAGG aggregated query

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, listagg

I am trying to eliminate repited values 
from aggregated results according [this  Oracle's recomendation](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1O85E4BHSBWN93G1B3M8SI2.html) :

```
with depts as (
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'CLERC' as job from dual union all
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'PRESIDENT' as job from dual union all

select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'ANALYST' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'ANALYST' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all

select 'SALES' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual
)

select d.department,
       listagg (d.job,', ' ) within group (order by d.job) jobs
  from depts d
 group by d.department
```

as you see field jobs contain repited values.

and Oracle reccomend to eliminate this in such way:

```
with depts as (
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'CLERC' as job from dual union all
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all
select 'ACCOUNTING' as department , 'PRESIDENT' as job from dual union all

select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'ANALYST' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'ANALYST' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'RESEARCH' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all

select 'SALES' as department , 'MANAGER' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'CLERK' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual union all
select 'SALES' as department , 'SALESMAN' as job from dual
)

SELECT d.department,
       (select LISTAGG(job,', ')
               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY job)
          from (select unique job job
                  from depts t
                 where t.department = d.department)) jobs
  FROM depts d
```

but it doesn't work with ver. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit.

Is this reccomendation correct?
As I know we couldn't send data into nested query onto second level of nesting.

Answer (score 3):

Starting Oracle 19c, `LISTAGG()` supports `DISTINCT`:

```
select department, listagg(distinct job, ',') within group(order by job) jobs
from depts
group by department
```

On earlier versions, a typical workaround is to `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subquery, then aggregate:

```
select department, listagg(job, ',') within group(order by job) jobs
from (select distinct department, job from depts) t
group by department
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a15cc93af706db63ec7f37bc478978cd)**:

```
DEPARTMENT | JOBS                   
:--------- | :----------------------
ACCOUNTING | CLERC,MANAGER,PRESIDENT
RESEARCH   | ANALYST,CLERK,MANAGER  
SALES      | CLERK,MANAGER,SALESMAN
```

Comment: So, Is recommendation on the Oracle's site correct?

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility is to deploy the feature that `LISTAGG` ignores the `NULL` values.

Simple `row_number the duplicates and`listagg`only the values with`rn = 1`

```
with dep as (
select 
  DEPARTMENT, JOB,
  row_number() over (partition by  DEPARTMENT, JOB order by JOB) as rn
from depts)
select 
 department, listagg(case when rn = 1 then job end, ',') within group(order by job) jobs
from dep
group by department
```